# Formatting a combo box

Tags: vb.net

I have added a ComboBox to a form, no additional formatting so far. I have a text box that the user enters a number of competitors (value) between 20 and 100 into. I want to populate the ComboBox so that the user can select a competitor from 1 to 100 in the ComboBox. So the user will be able to click the drop-down menu and select a competitor from a list of competitors, for example Competitor 1 to Competitor 100.
Please let me know if you need any extra info.

Comment: do you want that the values you enter in the textbox will appear on the combobox?

Comment: So the value that is entered into the text box will be the options. If the value entered into the text box is 75, the options in the ComboBox will be from Competitor 1 to Competitor 75.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, explanations included:

```
         yourComboBox.Items.Clear() 'to make sure the ComboBox is empty before populating and to avoid duplicating records
         If Val(yourTextbox.Text) > 0 Then 'basic checking
             For x = 1 To Val(yourTextbox.Text) 'loop from 1 up to the value you entered into the textbox
                 yourComboBox.Items.Add(x) 'add the value of x which holds the current loop number/competitor
             Next
         End If
```